# Yii2: How to save different data in two tables from one form?

Tags: mysql, yii2

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $tim = new PstkTim();
    $user = new User();

    if ($tim->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $user->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $tim->id = Yii::$app->generateid->getGUID();
        $tim->save();
        $idTim = $tim->id;
        $user->id = $tim->id;
        $user->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $tim->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
                    'tim' => $tim,
                    'user' => $user,                 
        ]);
    }
}
```

I am Trying to insert different data in two different tables. Table PstkTim and User, how do I insert in to User table in Yii2.

Comment: any errors? code looks ok.

Comment: it doesn't have error. save data does't not work, Data can save into Pstk Tim table, but into User table not

Comment: check for required fields in table, or try using `$user->save(false);`

Comment: can you print $_POST value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try with following way.

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $tim = new PstkTim();
    $user = new User();

    if ($tim->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $tim->id = Yii::$app->generateid->getGUID();
        $tim->save();
        $idTim = $tim->id;
        if($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
        {
            $user->id = $tim->id;
            $user->save(false);
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $tim->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
                    'tim' => $tim,
                    'user' => $user,                 
        ]);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you require any further information.

Comment: Welcome, please accept my answer if it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $tim = new PstkTim();
    $user = new User();

    if ($tim->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $tim->save();
        if($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
        {
            $user->id = $tim->id;
            $user->save();
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $tim->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
                    'tim' => $tim,
                    'user' => $user,                 
        ]);
    }
}
```